# How to show $[f][c]=[c][f]?$

Tags: algebraic-topology

$\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is  a group with respect to the product $[f][g]=[f.g]$

satisfy three properties

$1. $Associative

$2.$ Identity :$[c]$ where $c$ is the constant loop i,e $c(s)=x_0$ for any $s$

$3.$Inverse

**My question** : How to show the identity  properties in $\pi_1(X,x_0)?$

**My attempt** :

Here  $f$ is  a loop  so $f(0)=f(1)= c(s)=x_0$ where  $s \in [0,1]$

take the constant  path $c:[0,1] \to X$  defined by $c(s)=x_0$ for all $s$

Now we have to show that  $[f][c]=[f][c]=[f]$

According to Allen Book

since both  $f$ and $c$ are path  so by product path ,

$f.c (s)$ define by

$f\cdot g(s)= \begin{cases} 
      f(2s) & 0\le s\le 1/2 \\
      g(2s-1) & 1/2\le s\le 1 
   \end{cases}$

Note here $g=c$

$f\cdot c(s)= \begin{cases} 
      f(2s) & 0\le s\le 1/2 \\
      c(2s-1) & 1/2\le s\le 1 
   \end{cases}$

Now consider  $c(s)= f(1)$ for all $s \in I$

so $f\cdot c(s)= \begin{cases} 
      f(2s) & 0\le s\le 1/2 \\
      f(1) & 1/2\le s\le 1 
   \end{cases}$

Now by using the reparametrization theorem  we have  $(f.c).\phi \cong f.c$

i,e $f. c(s)$ is  reparametrization of $f$  by the map

$\phi(s)= \begin{cases}   2s \ \text{if} \ s \in [0,  1/2] \\ 1\  \text{if}\  s \in [1/2, 1] \end{cases}$

It satisfied the property $\phi(0)=0$ and $\phi (1)=1$

similarly
Now consider  $c(s)= f(0)$ for all $s \in I$

so $c f = \begin{cases} 
      f(0) & 0\le s\le 1/2 \\
      f(s) & 1/2\le s\le 1 
   \end{cases}$

Now by using the reparametrization theorem  we have  $(cf).\phi \cong c.f$

i,e $ c .f$ is  reparametrization of $f$  by the map

$\phi(s)= \begin{cases}   0 \ \text{if} \ s \in [0,  1/2] \\ 2s\  \text{if}\  s \in [1/2, 1] \end{cases}$

It satisfied the property $\phi(0)=0$ and $\phi (1)=1$

But here  $$ f.c(s) \neq c f(s)$$

therefore   $$[f][c]\neq [f][c]$$

This implies that $c$ doesn 't play the role of identity  in $\pi_1(X.x_0)$

**My confusion** :How to show $[f][c]=[f][c]?$

Comment: Hard to say without more particulars, but look carefully at the definition of the multiplication in $\pi_1$, and introduce your constant path into it.

Comment: Is this intuitively clear? If not, try drawing some pictures.

Comment: Have you consulted any algebraic topology books or lecture notes? They usually prove this.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I see the Allen hatcher book ,but i didn't understand  that concept given in book , so i post this problem here

Comment: Please use the "[Edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4008670/edit)" button under the question body to update your question with your attempt, instead of asking a new question. The question will automatically get bumped up when you edit, so it will still get the attention it needs.

Comment: thanks u @ElliotYu

Comment: Please edit this question to include info you would have included if you posted it again.

Comment: done ....@amWhy